# Artifactory virtual repository cannot resolve the Gradle-Artifactory plugin

Tags: gradle, artifactory, gradlew

So, I am at my wits end with trying to get the build-info-extractor-gradle plugin to work...sorry for venting.  ;-)

I'm using the gradle wrapper, specifying gradle 1.6, artifactory 3.0.0, and trying to specify a dependency on the build-info-extractor-gradle plugin 2.1.x-SNAPSHOT, as this is the [specified version](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+1.5+Publishing+Artifactory+Plugin) for gradle 1.5 and above.

I was attempting to follow this [tutorial video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhhCD5qtocg), but it must be out-dated because it is still referencing gradle 1.0 and specifying jfrog repo paths, which don't contain 2.x versions of the plugin.

---

#### Artifactory Setup

- local repo - "gradle-release-local" - layout set to gradle-default
- remote repo - "gradle-plugins" - slightly modified from the jfrog import - e.g. http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/gradle-plugins-snapshots
- virtual repo - "gradle" - "gradle-release-local" and "gradle-plugins"

---

#### Gradle Setup

settings.gradle (generated from artifactory)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://artifactory.build.somewhere.com:8081/artifactory/gradle'
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:2.1.x-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'artifactory'
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-release-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
            ivy {
                ivyLayout = '[organization]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml'
                artifactLayout = '[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]'
                mavenCompatible = false
            }
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
    }
}
```

My repository configuration does work, if I upload the jar, locally, e.g. this is how I got the build-info-extractor-gradle jar to be downloaded.  However, all of the dependencies fail, as you can see:

```
    $ gradlew tasks

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'classpath'.
    > Could not find commons-io:commons-io:2.0.1.
      Required by:
          unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:2.1.x-SNAPSHOT
    > Could not find org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.2.0.
      Required by:
          unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-
...
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED
```

---

Any ideas of what's wrong with either my gradle configuration or my artifactory repo configuration?  Why can't it resolve external dependencies from remote repositories?  Should I just add mavenCentral?

---

#### Update

I added mavenCentral() to the repositories, just to see what would happen and got:

```
$ gradlew tasks
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.0.1/commons-io-2.0.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/15/commons-parent-15.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.2.0/ivy-2.2.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/5/commons-parent-5.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.pom

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'classpath'.
> Could not find org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor:2.1.x-SNAPSHOT.
  Required by:
      unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:2.1.x-SNAPSHOT

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

---

#### Update #2

Started fresh.  Removed mavenCentral() and the locally uploaded jar and pom, then ran with --info and --refresh-dependencies:

```
$ gradlew --refresh-dependencies -i tasks
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using empty settings script.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'D:\repos\some_build\build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'some_build']
Evaluating root project 'some_build' using build file 'D:\repos\some_build\build.gradle'.
Compiling build file 'D:\repos\some_build\build.gradle' using BuildScriptClasspathScriptTransformer.
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://artifactory.build.somewhere.com:8081/artifactory/gradle/org/jfrog/buildinfo/build-info-extractor-gradle/2.1.0/build-info-extractor-gradle-2.1.0.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://artifactory.build.somewhere.com:8081/artifactory/gradle/org/jfrog/buildinfo/build-info-extractor-gradle/2.1.0/build-info-extractor-gradle-2.1.0.jar]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

So, clearly, my virtual "gradle" repo is not finding the artifact.  How can I tell if it is searching the remote "gradle-plugins" repo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doh!  It turns out that there are two very important configuration options, which **disable** remote repository resolution, which are selected by default (I can't recall checking/unchecking these?).

Anyways, here is what I did, in order to finally get the [gradle-artifactory plugin](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin?focusedCommentId=14811595) working, via resolution with my virtual repo:

- Disable global offline mode

  1. Go to: `Admin -> Configuration -> General`
  2. Ensure that the **Global Offline Mode** is deselected.  You'll see this option in `General Settings`
  3. Save
- Enable remote artifact resolution for your virtual repo

  1. Go to:
     `Admin -> Configuration -> Repositories -> {Edit the virtual repo} -> Advanced Settings`
  2. Ensure that the virtual repository has **Artifactory Requests Can Retrieve Remote Artifacts** selected
  3. Save
- Add the `gradle-plugins` remote repo to your virtual repo

  1. Choose `New` in remote repositories
  2. Give your remote repo a name, such as `jfrog-gradle-plugins`
  3. Set `URL` to http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/gradle-plugins
  4. Save
  5. Add the `jfrog-gradle-plugins` remote repo to your virtual repo's `Selected Repositories`, using the `Edit` option
  6. Save

Add following to `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${repositoryUrl}/libs-release"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath( group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo',
                   name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle',
                   version: '2.2.2')
    }
}
```

Add following to `gradle.properties`:

```
repositoryUrl = http://my.artifactory.server:8081/artifactory
repositoryUser = me
repositoryPassword = thisIsAPasswordStoredInMyUserDirectory
```

Hope that helps anyone struggling with getting started with integrating [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) and [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org).

### Helpful hint for debugging artifact resolution in Artifactory

Use the [trace](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-TraceArtifactRetrieval) REST API option.  For example:

http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/gradle-plugins/org/jfrog/buildinfo/build-info-extractor-gradle/2.2.2/build-info-extractor-gradle-2.2.2?trace

Comment: Note that I'm using very different settings now, compared to my original post.  It really was my own configuration issues, within Artifactory that were blocking me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the documentation is misleading :( Sorry about that. I am adding a clarification note now.

The page you are looking at is the documentation of a whole new (different and better) `artifactory-publish` plugin, but in the code you are using the classic `artifactory` plugin (which is also fine).

Please look at [this page](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin) for the documentation of `artifactory` plugin.

P.S. you're more than welcome to try the `artifactory-publish` plugin, it's awesome.

Comment: Sorry, I believe that the "artifactory" mistake is a copy and paste error from generating the build script.  I did notice that there was a newer version of the plugin (or perhaps an entirely different one?), and I was going to use "artifactory-publish".  Thanks for clarifying that and noting it in the documentation.

Comment: Regarding the virtual `gradle` repo - just add `gradle-plugins` to it in the settings.

Comment: Regarding the generated script with `artifactory` - https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-5800